# Smoke Flow Type "Fire" vs "Fire+Smoke"

Tags: smoke-simulation

In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65446/setting-up-smoke-domain-material-in-cycles) I showed images of a smoke simulation with Flow Type = Fire and Flow Type = Fire+Smoke. It seems that these two flow types have very little difference in their effects on the simulation.

But I guess the developers had reasons to create those two flow types. What is the nature of these two flow types and how do these flow types influence the smoke simulation ? I also mean how do these flow types influence the voxel data / simulation fields (availability, strength) ?
So where do these flow types really have a different impact on your simulation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flow type

"Fire" -  lets the flame generate first and then the smoke is created when the flame dies off (depending on your settings). The smoke is generated FROM the FIRE not the mesh.

"Fire+Smoke"- Generates fire AND smoke at the same time. Does not wait for the flame to die. The MESH generates the fire and smoke at the same time.

Comment: But if you look at the smoke and flame density for fire sim, it looks like smoke is emitted from the start.

Comment: Because the smoke is emitting from the flame not the mesh. They both have very little difference and it is hard to tell. You have to drastically change the settings to notice a slight difference. The reason you are seeing smoke from the start is because the "fire" is emitting smoke from the start (not the mesh). So it ends up looking like the same thing.