# When rendering fire and smoke the camera will not render the smoke/fire effect, but the viewport will

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, physics, camera

I have been working on making an explosion in the cycles render and have made the smoke and fire renderable through appropriate volume and attribute nodes, but for some reason it will render through the viewport in render mode, but not when I look through the camera.
When looking at it without the camera it appears as it should (Left)
However through the camera on the same frame it only appears as the original objects and no smoke or fire (Right)
[image]
Also, here is my Node setup
[image]
Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: You are seeing the viewport preview, you need to add a material to see it in the render. Have a look at the [answers to this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/65446/935)

Comment: Andrew Price has a great tutorial on this on his website or Youtube channel BlenderGuru. But as to your question, I think it has something to do with the material not being properly connected in the node editor. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I can’t believe nobody answered you more quickly.

Cycles doesn’t support smoke/fire with GPU. You can only use CPU. I know, what a bummer. I tried to do a tutorial the other day and it takes hours to render one frame with my 8 thread system…too slow and I can’t afford to by a 28 thread processor. I also tried render farms which are quick and work but one 10 second animation in 2k would have cost $16.

Of course once its in HD you see all sorts of stuff you don’t like so you’ll end up rendering it 5x to get what you want so that would have been $80. Not bad if you have a paying gig, you can factor it into the overall cost of the project.

If you are like me and just dipping your toe into the water, you’ll have to be patient and wait for the blender devs to create GPU support. If you have a real project that pays you can buy hardware (lots of CPU’s) or pay a render farm.

Good Luck.